# Code to Overlay inner part of an image to inner part of another image

Tags: c#, windows, image

[image]

As shown in image I need to overlay inner part of 2nd image to inner part of 1st image with rotating co-ordinates

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For example: to improve your question you could add the research you have already done trying to answer your question.

Comment: Please actually check the tags you include. I'm fairly sure that's not the "box" you're looking for, and the "Windows" part seems irrelevant too.

Comment: Also, this seems like a basic trigonometry question... calculating angles and polygon lengths from given coordinates. Solve that first; it's unrelated to programming.